# How to set max height for Bootstrap accordion

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, electron

I used [this](http://www.bootply.com/tGF9MEGbLM) template to create an accordion in Bootstrap.

I will probably have a lot more elements and can't figure out how to set the max height for the menu before the contents of the sublinks div become scrollable, since I have a limited window.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CraftByte/bjpLL5xn/)

I already tried applying max height to both `#menu` and the `.list-group.panel`

Comment: Can you put up a jsfiddle of your adapted version of this code?

Comment: Also, you'll need to put overflow-y: auto on the container in addition to a max-height to make it scroll (if it's not applied already).

Comment: @Dontfeedthecode I added the fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One item is 38px so you can set a `max-height` to the `.sublinks` div to the amount of divs you want to be shown so if you want two make it 76px or you want 3 make it 114px so on so on. Also i added `overflow: overlay;` so you won't see the items outside the accordion bit it still adds a scrollbar.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjpLL5xn/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of how to get your scrolling working with the code you've provided.

```
div.sublinks.collapse {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bjpLL5xn/3/

The issue you'll run into is that when expanded the Javascript is going to make the animation "jump".

Comment: Would there be a way to not make the animation jump and also to hide the scrollbar when it is not necessary

Comment: @AnžeJenšterle change overflow-y: scroll to overflow-y: auto firstly, I'll have to take a look at the jumping issue again.

Answer (score 0):

```
.panel-group .panel+.panel {
margin-top: 3px !important;
max-height: 90% !important; //90% height of your parent div and if it crosses y-axis scroller will be shown 
overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

Always use % and not px... you will have resolution issues later.